# How can I add a native Android action bar to my Air Mobile app?

Tags: android, actionscript-3, air

I have an Air mobile language learning app on the Google Play store that I'm happy with. It performs at 60fps and does what I need it to do.

I plan on adding more language packs and was wondering if I could use a native slide-out tray and action bar.

I have no idea if I can add any native android UI elements to an air mobile app. Does anyone have experience doing this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you'd need a native extension to interact with OS related items. checked out this yet? http://help.adobe.com/en_US/air/build/WS597e5dadb9cc1e0253f7d2fc1311b491071-8000.html

Answer (score 1):

This is technically possible using an ANE, though this **is not** what ANEs are meant for. ANEs are meant to give you access to native APIs, not native GUI elements. You should refrain from mixing AIR and native GUI elements. If you want to use native elements, you should switch to using native code.

If using native code is not something you wish to do, you can write your own implementation. The GUI structure is not difficult to mimic and AS3 offers a multitude of `MouseEvent`s and `TouchEvent`s that would allow you to properly write an AIR version of that GUI element (I've done so in the past, actually).

Another option is to use Flex or Starling or another GUI framework that offers a pre-built component for this. If you are not already using one, however, it will require you re-build your entire app.

Comment: I understand your comment, yet, having a UI implementation that mimicks native might make things worse as you'd need to update to the latest look and feel every time there's an OS update. My suggestion would be to either go with the native stuff or implement an obvious 'your own way'. Nonetheless, for what the OP was asking required an ANE.